# Checking for visibility of a toggled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, visibility

I have a button which toggles the visibility of a `<div>` below it and want to modify the text on the button depending on the visibility of said `<div>`.

Here is a live demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgjJG/1/)

If you click on "Saved Data", the first time it works correctly, but the next time you click the text does not change. This in itself is behaviour that I don't understand.

Now, I could use multiple handlers for `slideToggle()`, **however**, elsewhere in the code I also set intervals which load data next to "Cookie data:" and "Server data:". I don't want these intervals to do anything if the `<div>` is not visible so I use something like this:

```
    this.timer_cookiedata = setInterval(function(){
        if (!$savedData.is(':visible'))
        {
            return null;
        }
        // ..
    });
```

I'm worried these intervals are not going to work properly because of this `is(':visible')` business. So the question is, why does this happen (else statement is ignored), and what can I do to mitigate this?

Comment: I would just do [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/QgjJG/5/) ...

Comment: well tbh I knew how to get around the problem, I was just looking for an explanation of why my code didn't work as intended, but thanks for the short form version :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgjJG/2/). When you check for visibility right after you call `slideToggle`, jQuery may not have updated the visibility of the element yet since the animation takes some time to finish. For this exact reason, `slideToggle` has a callback you can use to perform operations after the animation has finished:

```
$(function () {
    var $savedData = $('#savedData');
    $('#btn-savedData')
        .click(function () {
        var $button = jQuery(this);

        //I'm checking the visibility in the callback. Inside the callback, 
        //I can be sure that the animation has completed and the visibility 
        //has been updated.
        $savedData.slideToggle('fast', function () {
            if ($savedData.is(':visible')) {
                $button.html('visible');
            } else {
                $button.html('not visible');
            }

        });
    });
});​
```